# citing multiple authors in text

Tags: citing

I would like to cite multiple authors in text but use a comma instead of a semicolon and there should be "and" before the last entry.

Currently, it looks like this

> Deet al. (2000); Mahajan et al. (2018); Wu et al. (2016) have demonstrated

but I want it like

> Deet al. (2000), Mahajan et al. (2018) and Wu et al. (2016) have demonstrated

in text citation. Notice that LaTeX sorts them alphabetically.

I tried `\cite{}` `\citet{}` and `\citet*{}` but always get the same first output.

I would like the change to have no effect on parenthesis citation.

I do not want a manual solution, I would like `LaTeX` to output the formatting the way I like without me writing the citation entries one by one.

Comment: Please provide a MWE, with the used classes etc. So we can try that. In this case that is really needed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can just use one such `\cite` and adjust `mincitenames` to three, to cite 3 authors at once, if you use ["biblatex"](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf).
Note biblatex will choose the first ones alphabetically if I remember correctly.
Also have a look at the doc, it also has an option for `maxcitenames`, if you want to provide an upper limit.

However, this only works if it is the same reference you cite. If you do cite different references, you approach should work, however – just repeat he `\cite`.

For a more detailed answer, you should possibly include a MWE.